# How to detect soft keyboard language?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I’m trying to apply different fonts for multiple languages when user changes soft keyboard language and starts typing, so I need to detect current keyboard language , I’ve been searching for quite a while now all solutions I found gets the locale not the keyboard, if there is any other way than detecting keyboard language I would be so grateful to know about it, thanks ..

Comment: Have you tried API getCurrentInputMethodSubtype() of InputMethodManager? It will have all the necessary information.

Comment: it gets the device's language not the keyboard's !

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        List<InputMethodInfo> inputMethodInfos = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

        final int N = inputMethodInfos.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            InputMethodInfo imi = inputMethodInfos.get(i);

            if (imi.getId().equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {
                Log.d("LOG",imi.getId());
                break;
            }
        }

execute and check the log for language

Answer (score 0):

```
private void method(){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    List<InputMethodInfo> inputMethodInfos = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    final int N = inputMethodInfos.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        InputMethodInfo imi = inputMethodInfos.get(i);
        if (imi.getId().equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {
            Log.d("LOG",imi.getId());
            break;
        }
    }
}
Please check the log for current language in soft keyboard
```

Comment: the log prints "Com.sec.android.inputmethid/.Samsung keybad" when i tested on samsung device !!

Comment: It is wokring for only Samsung Keyboard .Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?